# Using Threejs Canvas Renderer in JavaFX Webview Issue with transparency

Tags: three.js, javafx-2

I was messing around with Threejs inside of JavaFX webview and I sort of ran into a problem i was wondering if anyone had any idea.

I basically just dropped the canvas_interactive_cubes demo into a javaFX webview component and it works for the most part except for the fact that the ThreeJs scene always just seems to want to render solid black behind itself and not let the underlying web page show through. It works perfectly fine if I run the same demo out of firefox and mess with the page under the scene canvas.

I understand that threejs was never really meant to support FX Webview but I was just wondering if anyone had any idea what could be going on to cause this?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: What version of javafx are you using? Maybe that isn't supported in your current version of javafx. Try with the early access of javafx-8 https://jdk8.java.net/download.html and if keep failing. Plan to put an issue in the javaFX bug tracker: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @JBassmaster any luck?